# sql oracle - group by with join

Tags: sql, oracle

from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708761/sql-oracle-remove-duplicate-value/65708782#65708782), i tried to add join in the query, but i have this error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

```
SELECT ee.UP, max(ee.CODE_DEPT), dpt.LIBELLE_DEPT
  FROM ESP_ENSEIGNANT ee 
    INNER JOIN ESP_DEPT dpt 
        ON ee.CODE_DEPT = dpt.CODE_DEPT 
          group by ee.CODE_DEPT;
```

Comment: The unaggregated `SELECT` column is inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` keys.  What do not understand?

Comment: Your selection is ee.UP, max(ee.CODE_DEPT), dpt.LIBELLE_DEPT, so your group by should be GROUP BY ee.UP, dpt.LIBELLE_DEPT

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the columns which are not in the agg function. i.e ee.UP & dpt.Libelle_Dept as well.